# HP workstation Z420 cannot be turned on without unplugging and reinserting mainboard supply

Tags: workstation

A customer of mine has an HP Z420 workstation with a very strange behaviour.
The computer generally works well, but **occasionally refuses to turn on**.

The customer observed that **unplugging the power socket of the motherboard and reinserting it always worked**; after doing that, the computer turns on without problem. This is very boring as it involves kneeling down to open the case.

I went on site to see that from my own eyes. Although I'm aware that invisible solder cracks may be present, the power socket appeared to me being firmly soldered. I also could observe the malfunction and that the trick worked.

**In an attempt to solve the problem, the power supply has already be replaced** by a previous IT company, without success. I must admit that I don't know if the power cable was replaced as well.

As a first thing, I **replaced the BIOS battery** with a new one.
It seem have fixed the problem during about 10 days, but then the problem came again.

I suspect the presence of some parasitic current (due to capacitors?) that would prevent the computer turning on until the power socket is unplugged and reinserted.

Here are the specs:

- HP Workstation Z420 Tower
- Processor Xeon E5-1620 v2 @ 3,7 GHz
- Graphics: NVIDIA Quadro
- (8 GB RAM, 120 GB SSD, 1TB HDD, ...)

The power supply is a 600W one, and that seem sufficient according to the specs.

The HP warranty unfortunately expired.

**Are there known power supply problems with the motherboard of this workstation?**

Comment: @Alexander: Thank you for the improvements in the layout and the correction of the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: it was a failing capacitor.

Comment: Can you please tell the location of the capacitor ?